# Problem with imported case activities not appearing in the case record

Tags: civicase, mysql

Identical issue to: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=32904.msg140249#msg140249 which was never solved. Manually inserted a case with all of the tables mentioned in the post, yet it doesn't appear under job search in CiviCRM. They show in the database, but the GUI is blank.

Comment: Can you please add more detail, like some example data that is in the database? Otherwise it is extremely hard to answer your question, I would just be guessing. And also the CiviCRM version and CMS please?

Comment: `-- Create CiviCRM case
      INSERT INTO civicrm_case (
       case_type_id,
       subject,
       start_date,
       end_date,
       status_id,
       is_deleted
      )
      VALUES(
       CIVICRM_CASE_TYPE_ID,
       SessionId,
       ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME,
       ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME,
       2, -- Completed
       0 -- Not deleted
      );

      SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO CIVICRM_CASE_ID;`

Comment: `-- Create case start activity

      INSERT INTO civicrm_activity (
       activity_type_id,
       activity_date_time,
       status_id,
       priority_id,
       is_deleted,
       is_test,
       is_auto,
       is_current_revision
      )
      VALUES(
       148,
       ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME,
       2, -- Completed
       2,
       0,
       0,
       0,
       1
      );`

Comment: `-- Create case end activity

      INSERT INTO civicrm_activity (
       activity_type_id,
       activity_date_time,
       status_id,
       priority_id,
       is_deleted,
       is_test,
       is_auto,
       is_current_revision
      )
      VALUES(
       13,
       ACTIVITY_DATE_TIME,
       2, -- Completed
       2,
       0,
       0,
       0,
       1
      );`

Comment: `-- Set case owner
      INSERT INTO civicrm_case_contact (
       case_id,
       contact_id
      )
      VALUES (
       CIVICRM_CASE_ID,
       CIVICRM_CONTACT_ID
      );`

Comment: The version if Drupal, and latest CiviCRM. I can see some views in the database, but regenerating them hasn't made much difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing: 
`INSERT INTO civicrm_case_activity (
                            case_id,
                            activity_id
                        )
                        VALUES(
                            CIVICRM_CASE_ID,
                            CIVICRM_ACTIVITY_ID
                        );`

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as the correct one if it is the final answer!